# C#: will a vertical scrollbar appear on a listbox automatically?

Tags: listbox, scrollbar

If I fill a ListBox with items, will a vertical scrollbar automatically appear when there are too many items to display, or is there something that needs to be set for this to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**, that it will.

Answer (score 4):

ListBox only shows a vertical scroll bar when there are more items then the displaying area.

You can play with [`ListBox.ScrollAlwaysVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.scrollalwaysvisible%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Property if you want the bar to be visible all the time.